# How to set channel object using the channel id in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hello guys I'm trying to make a function that checks if few channels in the my discord server are full but I didn't know how to specify them.
The best idea I had was using the idea but couldn't set it to a channel object so how can I do that or is there any other good ideas?

```
def full(channel):
   while True:
       if len(channel.voice_members) == channel.user_limit:
           print("Wooo There is a full channel.")
       asyncio.sleep(10)
```

But I didn't know what to set the channel parameter.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the channel object either by ID or by name.

Use `discord.utils.get()` to return a channel by its name (example for voice channels):

```
channel = discord.utils.get(server.channels, name="Channel_name_here", type="ChannelType.voice")
```

Or you can use `discord.get_channel(id)` if you have the ID of the channel.

So for example if you have a list of channel names you want to check:

```
channel_names = ['channel1', 'channel2', 'channel3']
for ch in channel_names:
    channel = discord.utils.get(server.channels, name=ch, type="ChannelType.voice")
    full(channel)
```

See more in the [documentation](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html):

[discord.get_channel()](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel)

[discord.utils.get()](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to be a command, you can also take advantage of [converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters):

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def full(ctx, channel: discord.Channel):
    if len(channel.voice_members) == channel.user_limit:
        await bot.say("{} is full".format(channel.name))
    else:
        await bot.say("{} is not full".format(channel.name))
```