# How to specify a channel to set permissions?

Tags: python, button, discord.py, ticket-system

So I have a discord bot and I would like to add a ticketing system. I have the ticketing system I am just making a button for it. when you click the button it will allow you to talk on the channel. I can do `await interaction.channel.set_permissions(N/A)` but the `channel` function sets the channel to the one it was sent from, I need to specify the channel. how can I do that?

I allready have the channel saved in a varbile but I cant do this
`channel = await interation.guild.create_text_channel(name="inverters passion", overwrites=Overwritse, reason=f"inverters passion")`
`channel1 = bot.get_channel(int(channel.id))`
 `await interaction.channel1.set_permissions(N/A)` because It just dosent work. but if I use the property below ⬇️[image: code] It will work but as you can see it says"***The channel the interaction was sent from***" I need to specify the channel there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set channel object using the channel id in discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101717/how-to-set-channel-object-using-the-channel-id-in-discord-py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a channel object for your specific channel you can do the following:

```
channel = bot.get_channel(int("YOUR_CHANNEL_ID"))
```

You can get a channel's ID by having Developer Mode enabled on discord, and by right clicking a channel then clicking on "Copy ID".

Then, to set the permissions:

```
await channel.set_permissions(interaction.user, YOUR_PERMISSION)
```

Your bot may be named differently (maybe client or something else), so just change this to whatever you need. `Ex: something.get_channel()`

Comment: But how do I connect that to ```await interaction.channel.set_permissions(N/A)``` it wont work if I do  ```await interaction.bot.get_channel(int("YOUR_CHANNEL_ID")).set_permissions(N/A)```

Comment: The answer is correct, but not complete. You wish to do `channel = bot.get_channel("YOUR_CHANNEL_ID")` to get the channel, then `await channel.set_permissions(message.author, read_messages=True, send_messages=True)` where `message` is what your command receives.

Comment: True, I somehow forgot about this. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me I just read this post now and I would have never found this out on my own! thank you pluckplk and Carlos

Comment: Nice, do you mind marking the answer as correct? It's also good so people now it already got a correct answer, so they don't "waste" their time checking it.